# My app will not install on a HVGA device

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have an app that I've developed and I'm testing it across multiple devices.

The app will not install on a Samsung Galaxy Q (running Froyo with an HVGA 320x480 screen).

The minSdkVersion is 7 so that shouldn't be the problem.  It installs and runs fine on other. larger screen devices.

I have set the AndroidManifest.xml `<supports-screens>` flag to true for all screen sizes.

The error I'm seeing is "application not installed" when attempting to install the .apk.

It installs fine on the emulator with the same screen resolution and OS version.

Here's the manifest, please note that because the project is under NDA I've replaced identifiable elements with "%%%%".

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0"
      package="%%%%"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<application android:debuggable="false"
           android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
           android:icon="@drawable/icon"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:name="%%%%"
           android:theme="@style/Theme.LoadingBackground">
<activity android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:name="%%%%" />
<activity android:icon="@drawable/icon"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:launchMode="singleTask"
          android:name="%%%%"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:label="Store Front Widget"
          android:name="%%%%"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:taskAffinity="%%%%">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
<receiver android:label="%%%%"
          android:name="%%%%">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
             android:resource="@xml/widget_provider" />
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="%%%%" />
<service android:name="c%%%%" />
<service android:name="%%%%">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="%%%%" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
<service android:name="%%%%">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="%%%%" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
</application>
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"
                android:largeScreens="true"
                android:normalScreens="true"
                android:smallScreens="true" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="7" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of app you made?

If you are using camera resource in your app, then you must check your preview frame size.

```
public Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); 

        Parameters param = c.getParameters();

        List<Size> list = param.getSupportedPreviewSizes(); 
        int list_size = list.size();

        Log.e("list size", Integer.toString(list_size));

        int supportedH = list.get(2).height;
        int supportedW = list.get(2).width;

        Log.e("supported height", Integer.toString(supportedH));
        Log.e("supported width", Integer.toString(supportedW)); 

        param.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21); 
        c.setParameters(param);            
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("colorPicker", e.toString());
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Where would that be specified?

Comment: Also, would this be an issue at install-time?

Comment: yup, I have same problem in my project.

Comment: Get your camera instance's parameter. And get supportedpreview size. Kind of resolution problem popped here when I tried.

Comment: I've fiddled with the preview size parameter but so far haven't solved it.  However - removing any trace of the camera calls and the permission allows the app to install, so I'm confident you've pointed me in the right direction

Comment: Can you show me your code snippet?  Then I'll try to find what is the problem.

Comment: About 2years ago. finally! :)

Answer (score 1):

double check that there is not a version of your app installed on the device already. That same error is given if you try to install an app and one with the same package name, but a different signature already exists on the device.

If there is one it is probably signed with a different key (an expired debug key, or a release key or something) uninstall it and you should be good to go.

If you don't have another one installed, post your manifest file so we can take a look.

Comment: The project I'm working on is under NDA so I need to be careful what I post.  Is there a specific section of the manifest that is relevant?